# PHP MySQL not storing Marathi data in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a simple blog in which user can either enter text in English, Hindi, Marathi or Sanskrit, the problem is that I have set my database collocation to utf_8_bin.

Now the problem is that when I am inserting data from PHP script the data stored is in the format like `Ã Â¤Â¦Ã Â¥Â€Ã Â¤ÂªÃ Â¤Â¾Ã Â¤ÂµÃ Â¤Â²Ã Â¥Â€ Ã Â¤ÂšÃ Â¥ÂÃ Â¤Â¯Ã Â¤Â¾ Ã Â¤Â¹Ã Â¤Â¾Ã Â¤Â°Ã Â¥ÂÃ Â¤Â¦Ã Â¤Â¿Ã Â¤Â• Ã Â¤Â¶Ã Â¥ÂÃ Â¤Â­Ã Â¥Â‡Ã Â¤ÂšÃ Â¥ÂÃ Â¤Â›Ã Â¤Â¾!`

But when I am editing the data in the database and then copy-pasting the Marathi text in database then it is perfectly storing also the data is being viewed in the browser perfectly only while the time of storing it is not storing properly what might be the problem I have tried everything from past 1 hour I have gone through 50 links including the StackOverflow links.

This is my PHP Code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO posts(category_id, status, post_title, post_content, post_image, created, modified) VALUES('".$_POST['category']."', '".$status."', '".utf8_encode($_POST['title'])."', '".utf8_encode($_POST['content'])."', '".$image_path."', '".$created."', '".$modified."')";
$connection = $this->establish_connection();
mysqli_set_charset($conection,"utf8");

if($connection->query($query) === TRUE)
    {
        $connection->close();
        echo "success";
    }
else
    {
        $connection->close();
        echo "failed";//.$connection->error;
    }
```

`utf8_general_ci` is the table column collocation

Comment: Perhaps try to add an other query to set the charset in the database like `$connection->query("set names utf8");`. Add that code before the first if statement and comment the result. If that works, I'll add this comment as answer.

Comment: nopes didn't work